# Determine if a given timestamp is within the same day in postgresql

Tags: java, postgresql

I've got a PostgreSQL table with a "timestamp without time zone" field. At some given point I query this table, and I need those records where the timestamp is within the same day as when the query is performed. Here is the code:

```
 DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy/MM/dd HH:00:00");
 DateTime dt = new DateTime();
 String timeStampAsString = dt.toString(formatter);
 String select = "SELECT * FROM " + tableName + " WHERE " + tableName + ".timestamp >= '"+ timeStampAsString + "'";
 pst = dbConnection.prepareStatement(select);
 pst.execute();
```

I'm using Joda here as you can see, also I populate that table in some other point, so I now the format is correct (yyyy/MM/dd HH:00:00). Not really sure if I could pass a long directly to the query instead of converting to String, but this does not bother me right now.

Since the query condition is >= than "NOW" timestamp, this is very unlikely it returns something. What I need is to get the records within the same day as the "NOW" timestamp. I suppose I have to ask for upper and lower bounds, but I'm not sure how to calculate the lower boundary for this query...any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think you need this query

```
select *
from test1
where ts >= current_date and ts < current_date + interval '1 day';
```

or

```
select *
from test1
where ts >= now()::date and ts < now()::date + interval '1 day';
```

it's also possible to do

```
select *
from test1
where ts::date = now()::date;
```

but I think it will perform worse because conversion of data in column.

[**sql fiddle demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/d73b4/3)

Comment: I'll give it a try to both

Comment: Thanks for the link, is a great tool! It looks like the only one working for me is the third one, and execution time is quite close to the other two. Converting to date seems like a valid option.

Comment: actually it's strange that first and second doesn't work, could you provide an example in sqlfiddle?

Comment: I suppose they work but not for my current condition, which was "determine if the timestamp in the table is within the same day as when the query is performed", first and second are +1 day, which will never work in my scenario since there are no "future" timestamps in the table: there can only be past dates or also within the same day the query is launched. That's why first two are not working, maybe I didn't make myself clear enough, sorry. Still, this works, so I guee is a correct answer :)

Comment: I'd use `WHERE current_date <= ts AND ts < current_date + interval '1 day'`, as this way the values are in datetime order - visually `ts` is 'within' the `current_date` range.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way

```
long t1 = System.currentTimeMillis() / (24 * 3600 * 1000) * (24 * 3600 * 1000);
long t2 = t1 + 24 * 3600 * 1000;
String select = "SELECT * FROM " + tableName + " WHERE timestamp >= ? and timestamp < ?";
pst = dbConnection.prepareStatement(select);
pst.setTimestamp(1, new Timestamp(t1));
pst.setTimestamp(2, new Timestamp(t2));
...
```

Comment: Guess is just a typo, but you're passing t1 as argument twice...Looks good, I'll give it a try

Comment: -1: the math is wrong, and it doesn't deal with time zone and DST at all.

Comment: I don't need to deal with time zone since the field is "timestamp without time zone", and I'm populating this table on the same machine where I'm making the query, so the clock is the same...

Comment: This works, but could you explain what this is for: (24 * 3600 * 1000) * (24 * 3600 * 1000)?